# Wordpress - Search and display categories in results (NOT POSTS!)

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-list-categories

I have a lot of categories configured on WordPress and I want a way to let the user search (in a free-text input form) for a particular category.

Then, in the results page I only want to list those categories (NOT POSTS!) and show a link to the category page.

It's there a way (or plugin way) to achieve this easily?

**UPDATE**

And also how about searching for nested categories?, I mean, I have category A with a lot of child categories. It is possible to search for only those child categories (knowing the ID of A)?

**UPDATED: SOLUTION**

As @AhmadAssaf suggested I ended up making my own query. Here I post the code that I have used in my web:

**UPDATED**

The JOIN must be done with taxonomies.term_id and not taxonomies.term_taxonomy_id

```
function getCategories($string) {
    global $wpdb;
    $categories = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT terms.term_id, terms.name, taxonomies.description
        FROM wp_terms as terms
        LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy as taxonomies ON taxonomies.term_id = terms.term_id
        WHERE taxonomies.taxonomy = 'category'  && terms.name LIKE '%".$string."%'
        GROUP BY taxonomies.term_id
    ");
    return $categories;
}
```

Comment: may be this would help? http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-search-by-category-in-wordpress/

Comment: @GhazanfarMir I don't want to search for post in given category. I NEED to search categories

Comment: create a custom search page where you take in the query string and do filtering on `get_category` or fire a custome mySQL query

Comment: @AhmadAssaf Thanks for your answer! I was thinking about iterating and filtering the result of get_category(), but I'm affraid if this could be bad for performance if there are too many categories to look after. Could you please provide me an example using a custom MySQL Query?

Comment: Thank you very much @AhmadAssaf! Table names where with only one underscore and also term_relationships table was not necesary. Although, you guided me to the solution so I will mark your answer as correct! Also I will post the final query for everyone who wants it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can issue a custom mysql query to get all the categories details for a category that its name matches a string you pass

```
function getCat($string) {
    global $wpdb;
    $cat= $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT *
    FROM wp__term_relationships
    LEFT JOIN wp__term_taxonomy
       ON (wp__term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp__term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    LEFT JOIN wp__terms on wp__term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp__terms.term_id
    WHERE wp__term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'  && wp__terms.name LIKE '%".$string."%'
    GROUP BY wp__term_taxonomy.term_id
    ");
return $cat;
```

}